# Ошибка в коде с алгоритмом STL

Tags: массивы, матрицы, stl, вектор

1. Составить шаблон функции печати сформированного вами век-тора для любых типов его элементов. Размеры вектора в функцию не передавать!
2. Реализовать требуемый алгоритм задания методами контейнера vector и алгоритмами STL.
3. Если это не противоречит условию задачи, то заполнение век-тора производить с помощью функций rand иgenerate.

Сформировать и напечатать произвольную квадратную матрицу с целыми элементами, вводя с клавиатуры ее размер N. Определить сумму и произведение элементов каждой строки, исключая первый и последний элемент.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    srand(time(0));
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus_rus.1251");
    
    vector<vector<int> >dvec;
    
    int N;
    int i,j;
    int s,p;

    cout<<"Ââåäèòå ÷èñëî,êîòîðîå áóäåò ðàâíî êîëè÷å÷òâó ñòðîê è ñòîëáöîâ"<< "\t";
    cin>>N;
    
    cout<<endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        vector<int> vec;
        for(int j = 0;j<N; j++)
        {
        vec.push_back(rand()%100-50);
        dvec.push_back(vec);
        
        cout<<dvec[i][j]<<"\t";
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
    
        for(i = 0; i< N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<N; j++)
        {       
        
            if(j!=0 && j!=N)
                {
                
                s+=dvec[i][j];
                p*=dvec[i][j];
                
                }                       
    
     }
     
        cout<< i << "-é ñòðîêè"<<" "<<"Ñóììà"<<"="<< s<< "\t"<<"Ïðîèçâåäåíèå"<< "="<< p << endl;
       
    }
        
}
```

Ошибка: неверно заполняет и считает матрицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJqzJ.png][1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательно посмотрите на вот этот участок кода:

```
vector<int> vec;
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
{
    vec.push_back(rand() % 100 - 50);
    dvec.push_back(vec);

    cout << dvec[i][j] << "\t";
}
```

Что тут происходит? Вы добавляете первый элемент в `vec` и сразу добавляете вектор в `dvec`. Потом добавляете 2 элемент и опять добавляете в `dvec`. По этому у вас получается некая лесенка из сгенерированных элементов.

Правильней будет сначала заполнить строку `vec`, а потом уже её добавлять в `dvec`. Например так:

```
vector<int> vec;
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
{
    vec.push_back(rand() % 100 - 50);
    cout << vec[j] << "\t";
}
dvec.push_back(vec);
```

Так же хотел сказать про внутренний цикл, где находится сумма и произведение. Не легче начать с `j = 1` и идти до `j < N - 1`, а не использовать `if`?